# mysql attendance record per entry card per date and time

Tags: mysql

I am new to MySQL and I am working on a stored procedure where I am getting month, year and empid as inputs and I need to get the output as below.

I have a table `Emp_attendance` which has the following columns:

- empid
- login_date
- login_time
- status(in/out)

I have the following requirements:

1. I need to get the time worked by the employee in a day including night shifts
2. I need to record the absence details in a column on which day there is no entry for a employee on the basis of weekdays and weekends.

I have tried the below code:

```
create table Emp_attendance
empid int(11),
login_date date,
login_time time
login/logout_status smallint(6)
```

Sample data for Emp_attendance:

```
INSERT INTO Emp_Attendance VALUES(101,'2019-08-01','11:05:10',1);
INSERT INTO Emp_Attendance VALUES(101,'2019-08-01','20:05:10',2);
INSERT INTO Emp_Attendance VALUES(101,'2019-08-07','21:05:10',1);
INSERT INTO Emp_Attendance VALUES(101,'2019-08-08','06:05:10',2);
```

I have created the procedure below which is recording the min time and max time of a employee based on a particular date and emp id but I am not able to get the night shift time difference of a employee.
Also, I have a date column in my table but as I am short of data of all the dates of a month.

How do I show all the dates of a month and record as absence/present?

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE  PROCEDURE `proc_record_Emp_attend`(IN p_empID int,IN  p_month int,IN p_year int)
BEGIN    
select t1.empID, t1.login_date ,t1.INTIME,t1.OUTTIME,TIMEDIFF(t1.OUTTIME,t1.INTIME) as time_worked
from
(SELECT EA.login_date ,EA.empID,Min(EA.login_time) as INTIME,MAX(EA.login_time)  as OUTTIME
from Emp_Attendance EA
where 
EA.empID=p_empID 
AND MONTH(EA.login_date ) = p_month
AND YEAR(EA.login_date ) = p_year
group by EA.empID,EA.login_date)t1

END $$
DELIMITER;
```

Any help would be appreciated.

query for getting the overnight attendence which doesn't seem to be working fine.

```
SELECT 
  b.empid,
  b.login_date,
  (SUM(b.TIME_WORKED) OVER (PARTITION BY b.empid, b.login_date)) * 24 AS TIME_WORKED
FROM(SELECT a.empid,
            LEAD(a.login_time, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY a.empid, DATE_FORMAT(a.IOTime, '%d-%b-%Y') ORDER BY a.empid, a.login_time) -
            LEAD(a.login_time, 0) OVER (PARTITION BY a.empid, DATE_FORMAT(a.IOTime, '%d-%b-%Y') ORDER BY a.empid, a.login_time) AS TIME_WORKED,
            a.log_status,
            a.login_date
    FROM(SELECT empid,
                DATE_FORMAT(login_time,' %H:%i') AS login_time,
                CASE status WHEN 1 THEN 'IN' 
                            WHEN 2 THEN 'OUT' END AS log_status,
                DATE_FORMAT(login_time, '%d-%b-%Y') AS login_date
           FROM Emp_attendance
        ) a 
    ) b
WHERE b.log_status ='IN'
ORDER BY b.login_date, b.empid;
```

Comment: Sorry could you expand on your problem statement "I am not able" - what problem have you encountered? Cheers

Comment: Hi, i want to fetch the time difference of an employee who works at overnight which i am unable to find a way to do it.

Comment: For the first problem, you can add logout_date and logout_time columns just like login one's and remove login/logout_status now every time employee logs in you will insert with logout time as null and will update it when an employee logs out, then you can calculate work time easily by taking difference of those two columns

Comment: Your table creation statement does not look like MySQL

Comment: And for the second problem, I think you need to create a new table with all the working days and then join it Emp_Attendance with left outer join to check employee is present or absent on a particular date

Comment: @Strawberry yeah i know i was giving the overview of the table structure to get an idea to make it work.

Comment: @AbhaySehgal i don't have a different column for recording the logout out data. The login_date column is the only date column which gets the entry for both the login and logout date on the basis of entry/exit status. i have provided the insert queries to give an idea how the table looks like. Can you give an idea to make it work using a single date column?

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Ok so you just repeated "I am unable". You have to state a specific problem.

Comment: i think i have provided enough info to find the solution of this problem @Strawberry  Could you please let me know if you didn't get my problem statement ?

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica i need the query to get the time difference of the employees working overnight through the above mentioned table structure. Like i mentioned before, your help would be appreciated.

Comment: You still haven't told us what the problem is. Did you get an error message? Did you encounter some _specific_ problem? If you're just asking us to do it for you, that's not what happens here...

Comment: i am not asking you to do it for me. my logic doesn't seem to be working, so i thought i might get help in getting a better logic. This is what i have tried till now.

Comment: I have edited the post with the query which isn't giving the correct results.@LightnessRaceswithMonica